# How to change mount to grant user write permissions?

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, tomato

I am on TomatoUSB, and using the feature to have a NAS.

The only way I can write to the Samba share is if I force root:

```
[global]
interfaces = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.1/24
bind interfaces only = no
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = TOMATO
security = share
wins support = yes
name resolve order = wins lmhosts hosts bcast
guest account = nobody

[Public]
path = /mnt/sda2
read only = no
public = yes
only guest = yes
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
comment = Network share
force user = root
writeable = yes
```

I dont really like the idea having to use root to allow write access to my share. I have a samba account created already named nobody to allow access to the share. However every time I try to write I get access denied error.

fstab:
/`dev/sda2   /mnt/sda2 vfat defaults 0 0`

Further more every time I try to `chmod 777 /tmp/mnt/sda2` the permissions are not changed, and no error is produced. They stay 755.

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jun  4 01:49 sda2
```

Basically; how can I give the user nobody write permissions to my mount?

```
dev name: /dev/sda2
dev mount: /tmp/mnt/sda2
```

Answer (score 2):

The FAT filesystem does not support Unix permissions, so the ones specified in `fstab` apply to all files.

Add the options `fmask=0111,dmask=0` to give *a+rw* to files and *a+rwx* to directories.